# i18n for Python Scripts in Zope (restricted python)

Tags: python, internationalization, zope

Here is what I'm trying to do: I want to enable i18n support for my zmi python scripts in a gettext compatible way, with the '_'-function.

Here is what I did so far. In a module of my Zope Product, I run:

```
import gettext, __builtin__    
t = gettext.translation('myDomain', LOCALESPATH, languages=['de'], fallback=True)
__builtin__._ = t.gettext
```

Calling _ in an (unrestricted) External Method works fine, it returns the translation, as expected.

```
def testI18n():
  return _('text to be translated')
```

If I try this in a Zope "Script (Python)" which uses RestrictedPython to execute its code, I get a NameError: "global name '_' is not defined".

This is my workaround:

```
from myModule import myTranslator as _
print _('text to be translated')
return printed
```

which works well (myModule has to be allowed for Python Scripts, of course).

But I'm curious if there is a way to have _ as a builtin function in restricted python scripts, and if it is possible to extend the safe_builtins in RestrictedPython.Guards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, Zope already has gettext-compatible i18n packages available for you, in the form of [`zope.i18n`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.i18n). This is already part of Zope itself, no need to install it separately.

Secondly, don't muck about with `__builtin__`; simply *import* the message factory into a module and name it `_`.

In your Zope Product `__init__.py` you add a message factory for this:

```
from zope.i18nmessageid import MessageFactory
from AccessControl import ModuleSecurityInfo

YourDomainMessageFactory = MessageFactory('your.domain')

ModuleSecurityInfo('your.packagename').declarePublic('YourDomainMessageFactory')
```

Now you have a message id factory that can be imported into any of your project python files, *including* restricted files:

```
from your.packagename import YourDomainMessageFactory as _

message = _('Your message to be translated')
```

Note how we still use `_` as the local name in the code.

You register your message catalogs with a short amount of ZCML:

```xml
<configure
    xmlns:i18n="http://namespaces.zope.org/i18n">

    <i18n:registerTranslations directory="locales" />

</configure>
```

where `locales` is a subdirectory of the directory the `configure.zcml` file lives. `zope.i18n` expects to find `<REGION>/LC_MESSAGES/yourdomain.mo` and optionally, `<REGION>/LC_MESSAGES/yourdomain.po` files in the registered directory; `.po` files are automatically compiled into `.mo` files for you as needed.

ZPT page templates use `zope.i18n` message catalogs by default, see [ZPT i18n support](http://wiki.zope.org/zope3/ZPTInternationalizationSupport).

If you need to translate something manually, use the `zope.i18n.translate` function:

```
from zope.i18n import translate

message = _('Your message to be translated')
print translate(message, target_language='de')
```

Most of the [Plone i18n manual](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/internationalization-i18n-and-localization-l10n) applies to generic Zope applications.

If you absolutely *have* to be able to poke things into `__builtins__`, then by all means directly manipulate `RestrictedPython.Guards.safe_builtins`; it's a dictionary:

```
from RestrictedPython.Guards import safe_builtins

safe_builtins['_'] = t.gettext
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Unfortunately I have problems getting it working. First, I had already tried setting the safe_builtins exactly as you suggest, but it does not make any difference: in web-based Python Scripts I get the NameError. Do they use different \__builtins\__? Second, while gettext.translation works, myDomainMessageFactory does not, it returns the string to be translated. And how can I tell it what language I want it to be translated in?

Comment: @Rastaf: Use an explicit `translate(message)` call to have message ids translated. Normally, we use these in views and as they end up in a ZPT template, that translates these for us. I'm not certain about `safe_builtins`, never use it myself. :-)

Comment: It took me some time, but now I got the i18nmessageid working. Thanks, that's exactly what I need, although I didn't realize it right away ;)

Comment: @sebasgo: `_` is the conventional name for the message factory; see the text before:  *simply import the message factory into a module and name it `_`.*

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know, but you are still importing `YourDomainMessageFactory`, only  with a new name (`_`). So if you want to let the import succeed from Restricted Python you have to declare `YourDomainMessageFactory` public, not `_`. I just confirmed this in my current project.

Comment: @sebasgo: blah, you are right. It is imported as one, bound to another name. Sorry!